# How it works the Bootstrap 5 Sass

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm trying to understand how bootstrap-sass compiled like modifying variables, mixin, etc. I set up Dart sass in the system and used vs code to compile sass. My **Project Structure** is below.

```
BootSass/
    ├── assets
    │   ├── css
    │   │    └── main.css
    │   └── scss
    │       └── main.scss
    └── node_modules
        └── bootstrap
            └── scss
                └── bootstrap.scss
```

in vs code terminal in my project root **BootSass**, I compiled with this sass command.

```
sass -w -s expanded assets/scss/main.scss assets/css/main.css
```

in **main.scss** I imported the Bootstrap and it's compiling perfectly.

```
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

My question is how it compiled if the node module file is blank also after I deleted the inside all codes of **bootstrap.scss**.

```
node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss
```

the **main.css** after compilation is

[image]

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?  Your question is unclear.